# I am migrating my sitecore from sitecore 6.5 to 8.1

Tags: sitecore

I am migrating a website using Sitecore 6.5 to sitecore 8.1

Below is the code written in sitecore 6.5, I need to change to sitecore 8.1 version.
when I used sitecore.analytics 8.1 version, it is showing error.
can some help in getting the issue resolved for the below code

```cs
public static int GetPageVisits(ID pageId)
{
    return DataAdapterManager.Provider.Sql.ReadOne<int>(CommandText, ReadPageViews, new object[] { "currentItemId", pageId.ToString() });            
}
```

below is the error I am getting...

> Error 1   'Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.DataAdapterProvider' does not
>   contain a definition for 'Sql' and no extension method 'Sql' accepting
>   a first argument of type
>   'Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.DataAdapterProvider' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Hi Devlin, below is the error I am getting...
Error 1 'Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.DataAdapterProvider' does not contain a definition for 'Sql' and no extension method 'Sql' accepting a first argument of type 'Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.DataAdapterProvider' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore Analytics API changed in xDB, From your code i can see you are trying to get page visits number, For that you can use the following API

```cs
VisitStatistics PageStats = Sitecore.Analytics.Testing.TestManager.GetPageStatistics(Guid, DateTime, DateTime)
```

Guid parameter is the item ID, the 2 DateTime parameters are for the interval time range you want to get the page statistics for.

Comment: Thanks ahmed.. but I am using the below code

public static int GetPageVisits(ID pageId)
        {
            return DataAdapterManager.Provider.Sql.ReadOne<int>(CommandText, ReadPageViews, new object[] { "currentItemId", pageId.ToString() });            
        }

        private static int ReadPageViews(DataProviderReader reader)
        {
            return DataAdapterManager.Provider.Sql.GetInt(0, reader);
        }

Comment: @Sree As i stated in my answer, Sitecore analytics API has changed, Your previous code will not work anymore, Try to use the new API i included in the answer